# It is possible to optimize SQL "order by limit" with large offset

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 450000 records at MySQL.
The query below cost nearly 3s. Is it possible to lower the time cost?

```
SELECT * FROM table order by id desc limit 400000, 8000
```

Comment: Perhaps `order by id asc limit 42000, 8000`?

Comment: why `select *` ?  just select the fields that you really need.  `select firstName, lastName...`

Comment: you can set LIMIT some small value instead of 8000

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. I'l like to know if there is solution for limit optimization with large offset(400000).

Comment: add a field+index with the row Number WHERE rowid BETWEEN 400000 AND 408000 , or use the id if it possible

Comment: Try to use partitioning when you have big amount of data. See here for more: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table-partition-operations.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `id` is indexed, then there's not a lot you can do - apart from what's been suggested above. That said, I'm surprised it's soo slow...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|   450000 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.12 sec)

SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY i DESC LIMIT 400000,8000;
...
8000 rows in set (0.20 sec)
```